# Sorting Outlook tasks by user-defined field in VBA

Tags: vba, outlook

I'm trying to sort my tasks by a user-defined field that I call "Seq". When I do this with VBA it seems to do nothing.  However, this works perfectly fine when sorting by default fields, like DueDate.  Does anyone have a solution?  I am including my code and results.  I'm using Outlook 2010. Thanks in advance!

Here is the code:

```
Sub TestSort()
    Dim ToDoFolder As Folder
    Dim Task As TaskItem
    Dim Sel As Outlook.Items
    Dim InitStartTime As Date
    Dim RemindTime As Date
    Dim FilterString As String

'FORCE CHANGE CURRENT FOLDER TO BE "TO DO LIST" AND VIEW TO BE "Debug (Filter:TEST)"
    Set ToDoFolder = Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderToDo)
    Set Application.ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder = ToDoFolder
    ToDoFolder.Views.Item("Debug (Filter:TEST)").Apply

'AUTOMATICALLY SELECT TASK ITEMS TO BE WORKED WITH

    FilterString = "@SQL=" & ToDoFolder.Views.Item("Debug (Filter:TEST)").Filter
    Set Sel = ToDoFolder.Items.Restrict(FilterString)

'SHOW ORIGINAL SORTING
    Debug.Print Chr(13); "Sort by Original"
    Call CheckSort(Task, Sel)

'SORT TASKS IN MY SELECTION (AND CHECK SORT)

    Sel.Sort "[Seq]", False
    Debug.Print Chr(13); "Sort by Seq Ascending"
    Call CheckSort(Task, Sel)

    Sel.Sort "[Seq]", True
    Debug.Print Chr(13); "Sort by Seq Descending"
    Call CheckSort(Task, Sel)

    Sel.Sort "[DueDate]", False
    Debug.Print Chr(13); "Sort by DueDate Ascending"
    Call CheckSort(Task, Sel)

    Sel.Sort "[DueDate]", True
    Debug.Print Chr(13); "Sort by DueDate Descending"
    Call CheckSort(Task, Sel)

End Sub

Sub CheckSort(Task As Outlook.TaskItem, Sel As Outlook.Items)

'CHECK THAT IT WAS SORTED CORRECTLY

    Debug.Print Chr(13);
    For Each Task In Sel
        Seq = Task.UserProperties.Find("Seq").Value
        Debug.Print Seq & " " & Task.Subject & " " & Task.DueDate
    Next Task
End Sub
```

Here are the results:

```
Sort by Original

2 Test 1 6/6/2018
4 Test 2 6/8/2018
1 Test 3 6/10/2018
3 Test 4 6/9/2018

Sort by Seq Ascending

2 Test 1 6/6/2018
4 Test 2 6/8/2018
1 Test 3 6/10/2018
3 Test 4 6/9/2018

Sort by Seq Descending

2 Test 1 6/6/2018
4 Test 2 6/8/2018
1 Test 3 6/10/2018
3 Test 4 6/9/2018

Sort by DueDate Ascending

2 Test 1 6/6/2018
4 Test 2 6/8/2018
3 Test 4 6/9/2018
1 Test 3 6/10/2018

Sort by DueDate Descending

1 Test 3 6/10/2018
3 Test 4 6/9/2018
4 Test 2 6/8/2018
2 Test 1 6/6/2018
```

Comment: If you try sorting in the UI there is a "You cannot sort by this field." message. You may have to write your own sort program.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the comment, niton.

I've solved the problem.  I'm posting it here in case anyone has been having the same issue.

I don't know why, but the sort just wont work with a user-defined field when using an Items object.  However...I got it to work fine while using the Table object! :) Check out the new code below.

```
Sub TestSort()
    Dim ToDoFolder As Folder
    Dim Task As TaskItem
    Dim Sel As Outlook.Table
    Dim InitStartTime As Date
    Dim RemindTime As Date
    Dim FilterString As String
    Dim oCol As Outlook.Column

'FORCE CHANGE CURRENT FOLDER TO BE "TO DO LIST" AND VIEW TO BE "Debug (Filter:TEST)"
    Set ToDoFolder = Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderToDo)
    Set Application.ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder = ToDoFolder
    ToDoFolder.Views.Item("Debug (Filter:TEST)").Apply

'AUTOMATICALLY SELECT TASK ITEMS TO BE WORKED WITH

    FilterString = "@SQL=" & ToDoFolder.Views.Item("Debug (Filter:TEST)").Filter
    Set Sel = ToDoFolder.GetTable(FilterString)

'CHECK DEFAULT COLUMNS
    For i = 1 To Sel.Columns.Count
        Set oColumn = Sel.Columns.Item(i)
        Debug.Print oColumn.Name
    Next i

'ADD COLUMN FOR USER-DEFINED FIELD "SEQ"
    Sel.Columns.Add ("Seq")

'SHOW ORIGINAL SORTING
    Debug.Print Chr(13); "Sort by Original"

    Call CheckSortTable(Sel)

'SORT TASKS IN MY SELECTION (AND CHECK SORT)

    Sel.Sort "[Seq]", False
    Debug.Print Chr(13); "Sort by Seq Ascending"
    Call CheckSortTable(Sel)

    Sel.Sort "[Seq]", True
    Debug.Print Chr(13); "Sort by Seq Descending"
    Call CheckSortTable(Sel)

    Sel.Sort "[DueDate]", False
    Debug.Print Chr(13); "Sort by DueDate Ascending"
    Call CheckSortTable(Sel)

    Sel.Sort "[DueDate]", True
    Debug.Print Chr(13); "Sort by DueDate Descending"
    Call CheckSortTable(Sel)

End Sub

Sub CheckSortTable(oTable As Outlook.Table)

    Dim Task As Outlook.Row

'CHECK THAT IT WAS SORTED CORRECTLY

    Debug.Print Chr(13);
    Do Until (oTable.EndOfTable)
        Set Task = oTable.GetNextRow()
        Seq = Task("Seq")
        Debug.Print (Seq & " " & Task("Subject") & " " & Task("DueDate"))
    Loop
End Sub
```

...and the new output...

```
EntryID
Subject
CreationTime
LastModificationTime
MessageClass
DueDate
PercentComplete
IsRecurring

Sort by Original

2 Test_1 6/8/2018
4 Test_2 6/10/2018
1 Test_3 6/8/2018
3 Test_4 6/10/2018

Sort by Seq Ascending

1 Test_3 6/8/2018
2 Test_1 6/8/2018
3 Test_4 6/10/2018
4 Test_2 6/10/2018

Sort by Seq Descending

4 Test_2 6/10/2018
3 Test_4 6/10/2018
2 Test_1 6/8/2018
1 Test_3 6/8/2018

Sort by DueDate Ascending

2 Test_1 6/8/2018
1 Test_3 6/8/2018
4 Test_2 6/10/2018
3 Test_4 6/10/2018

Sort by DueDate Descending

4 Test_2 6/10/2018
3 Test_4 6/10/2018
2 Test_1 6/8/2018
1 Test_3 6/8/2018
```